# Error unit testing a method that uses db.savechanges() in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

So I'm working on my unit tests for the controller. Currently the test calls a method and within that method it saves a object to the database. For some for me unknown reason it however says that 0 rows are updated. When I run the program normal it all works but for some reason in the Unit tests it doesn't. It might have to do with the fact I'm using the Moq library to mock the database.

Here's the mocking:

```
var data1 = new List<Person> { test5, test6 }.AsQueryable();

var dbSetMock1 = new Mock<IDbSet<Person>>();
dbSetMock1.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data1.Provider);
dbSetMock1.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data1.Expression);
dbSetMock1.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data1.ElementType);
dbSetMock1.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data1.GetEnumerator());

var mockContext1 = new Mock<PersonDBContext>();
mockContext1.Setup(x => x.Persons).Returns(dbSetMock1.Object);
var fakeHttpContext1 = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var fakeIdentity1 = new GenericIdentity("Richard");
var principal1 = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity1, null);

fakeHttpContext1.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(principal1);
var controllerContext1 = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext1.Setup(t => t.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext1.Object);

var service1 = new PersonController(mockContext1.Object);
service1.ControllerContext = controllerContext1.Object;

List<Person> testlistformanagepeople = new List<Person>();
testlistformanagepeople.Add(test5);
testlistformanagepeople.Add(test4);

ViewResult resultcall = (ViewResult) service1.ManagePeople();

ViewResult resultofmanagepeople = (ViewResult)service1.ManagePeople(testlistformanagepeople);
List<Person> resultaftermethod = (List<Person>)resultofmanagepeople.Model;

Assert.IsTrue(resultaftermethod.Count.Equals(1));
```

And the method I'm testing:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ManagePeople(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Person updatedperson in persons)
                    {
                        if (updatedperson.PeopleManagerApproved)
                        {
                            foreach (Person personindb in db.Persons.ToList())
                            {
                                if (personindb.ID == updatedperson.ID && !personindb.PeopleManagerApproved)
                                {
                                    personindb.PeopleManagerApproved = true;
                                    db.Entry(personindb).State = EntityState.Modified;
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
            }
            //return the remaining people.
            List<Person> peopletocheck = new List<Person>();
            peopletocheck = (from p in db.Persons where p.PeopleManager.Equals(User.Identity.Name) && !p.PeopleManagerApproved select p).ToList();
            return View(peopletocheck);
        }
```

and then last the error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Smoelenboek.Controllers.PersonController.ManagePeople(IEnumerable`1 persons) in c:\Users\donkelam\Documents\Visual_studio_projecten\Smoelenboek\Smoelenboek\Controllers\PersonController.cs}
```

Comment: Did you use break point to find at which line of the code the error gets

Comment: yup db.SaveChanges() and i've checked with error handling how the database looks AFTER the method was called and it does save it to the database cause the expected result is 1 object and it returns 1 object

Comment: If you are writing Unit Test, you don't want to invoke EF code. You should mock everything except the custom logic in your CUT.

Comment: well i'm trying to mock everything... but how do you mock the db.savechanges method?

Comment: You shouldn't need to mock DbContext directly. Define an interface IDataContext, implement a class that derive from DbContext as well. Now you can actually use IDataContext in your controller. That will give you easy way to mock it.

Comment: wasn't Moq made to prevent using interfaces? At least that's what i'm reading all around

Comment: Can you share link where you read it, generally curious.

Comment: well it seems moq can actually mock this with: mockContext1.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Returns(1); and the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/data/dn314429.aspx might not say it literally but as you can see you can mock all the methods etc with Moq so no need for an interface anymore